# Nginx serve another file when possible

Tags: nginx, compression, static-content

I currently compile my assets with Webpack's BrotliPlugin, which creates a separate file, brotli-encoded, i.e.:

- `style.css`
- `style.cssb`

Here's what I want to achieve:
Consider the HTML page requests `style.css`.

IF

- The user sent `br` into its `Accept-Encoding` request header
- AND the corresponding brotli file exists (`style.cssb` in this case):

THEN

- Serve the corresponding brotli file content `style.cssb`
- With a `Content-Type: text/css` response header
- With a `Content-Encoding: br` response header

OTHERWISE

- Act as normal, just serve `style.css`

Here's part of my config so far:

```
map $http_accept_encoding $accepts_brotli {
    default false;
    "~*br" true;
}
location ~* (.*).(css|js)$ {
    set $brotli_uri "${uri}b";
    set $brotli_file "${request_filename}b";
    set $should_use_brotli "";
    if ($accepts_brotli = true) {
        set $should_use_brotli "Y";
    }
    if (-f $brotli_file) {
        set $should_use_brotli "${should_use_brotli}Y";
    }
    if ($should_use_brotli = YY) {
        add_header X-URI $brotli_uri;
        add_header Content-Encoding br;
    }

    add_header X-FOO "bar";
    try_files $brotli_uri $uri;
}
```

Result:

- X-URI is present in response
- X-FOO is not
- Uncompressed content is still served

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PS: I'd like to avoid Nginx' brotli plugin since I can compute compression at compile time, which prevents CPU overhead upon each request.

Comment: There is brotli_static directive to serve precompressed files https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli/blob/master/README.md#brotli_static

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't notice this. Thanks!